# Time series data using ggplot: how use different color for each time point and also connect with lines data belonging to each subject?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data from several cells which I tested in several conditions: a few times before and also a few times after treatment. In ggplot, I use color to indicate different times of testing. 
[image]

Additionally, I would like to connect with lines all data points which belong to the same cell. Is that possible?...

Here is my example data (https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqvgm4yu6epijgm/df.csv?dl=0) and a simplified code for the plot:

```
df$condition = as.factor(df$condition)
df$cell = as.factor(df$cell)
df$condition <- factor(df$condition, levels = c("before1", "before2", "after1", "after2", "after3")

windows(width=8,height=5) 

ggplot(df, aes(x=condition, y=test_variable, color=condition)) +
labs(title="", x = "Condition", y = "test_variable", color="Condition") +
geom_point(aes(color=condition),size=2,shape=17, position = position_jitter(w = 0.1, h = 0))
```

Comment: Hi! For each cell you have 3 after and 2 before.. how would you connect 3 dots to 2 dots? Or do you want to connect the means?

Comment: @StupidWolf, I think it is a time serie labeled `before1`, `before2`, `after1`, `after2`, `after3`. I agree that the labeling of timepoints could be quite confusing.

Comment: Try adding a `group` argument inside `aes`. If I'm understanding your description, that could be `group = Cell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you get in the wrong direction for your code, you should instead group and colored each points based on the column `Cell`. Then, if I'm right, you are looking to see the evolution of the variable for each cell before and after a treatment, so you can order the x variable using `scale_x_discrete`.

Altogether, you can do something like that:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = condition, y = variable, group = Cell)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = condition))+
  geom_line(aes(color = condition))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("before1","before2","after1","after2","after3"))
```

[image]

Does it look what you are expecting ?

**Data**

```r
df = data.frame(Cell = c(rep("13a",5),rep("1b",5)),
                condition = rep(c("before1","before2","after1","after2","after3"),2),
                variable = c(58,55,36,29,53,57,53,54,52,52))
```

Comment: Alternatively, we could keep the different colors for `condition` as long as we have the `group = cell` as well. In that case I like making the connecting lines gray:   `ggplot(df, aes(x = condition, y = variable, group = Cell, color = condition)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(color = "gray70")+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("before1","before2","after1","after2","after3"))`

Comment: You're right, it is a good suggestion that is closer to what the OP proposes as an initial graph. However, my understanding of the question is that these data looks to be a time serie for different cells. Maybe I'm wrong. We'll see OP's reply.

Comment: I modified the title of the question after reading everyone's kind remarks. I have to agree that maybe what I am trying to do is not the best way to represent such data. Maybe this is why I could not find any examples how to make the plot I wanted! I would like to accept the solutions provided by both Jon Spring and dc37. `scale_x_discrete` is crucial in such plots and I did not know how to do that! I ordered factor levels with `df$condition <- factor(df$condition, levels = c("before1", "before2", "after1", "after2", "after3")` but that did not fully work...

Comment: I edited my answer to provide color in function of `conditions`. What do you mean by " did not fully work" ? Do you get the same plot when following my example ?

Comment: Everything what you suggested works! I meant that I was unable to control the order on the x-axis before receiving your help.

Comment: OK I understand ;) Glad you learn to manipulate the order of axis in ggplot ;)